# Get last message from kafka consumer console script

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We can get every messages from Kafka by doing:

```
 bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning
```

Is there a way to get **only the last message** ?

EDIT:

If you just want to monitor some messsages (`--max-messages 10`) in your stream, a convenient command is :

`watch -n5 "./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic auction --max-messages 10"`

Comment: How about  `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --from-beginning --timeout-ms 10 | tail -n 1`   (The timeout-ms kills the consumer after its read everything)

Comment: increase the timeout value if there is huge data

Comment: @natetitterton your answer is "get all items off the topic" show the first one. not very efficient

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'm not aware of any automatism, but using this simple two step approach, it should work. 
Note that in my case it was a partitioned topic, you can leave the params for it out in case you have a unpartitioned one:

**1) Get max offset for your topic (+ their partitions):**

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic mytopic

mytopic:2:11
mytopic:1:7
mytopic:0:15
mytopic:3:8
```

**2) Choose a topic (+ partition) and provide the *offset - n* as parameter:**

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic mytopic --offset 10 --partition 0
```

The last n messages of the topic will be printed to the console.
In my example, it will show 5 messages (= 15-10).

Comment: It should be noted that this method is not reliable in general, because not every offset necessarily holds a message. There may be gaps, for instance in case of compacted logs or aborted transactions.

Comment: We can also use a client to install on your computer to have this information among a lot more : https://www.conduktor.io/ (thanks Stephane Maarek and Stéphane Derosiaux)

Comment: Why we don't specify consumer ID here? AFAIK offsets should be consumer group specific, isn't it?

Comment: @BorisMitioglov: Offsets are partition specific.

Answer (score 7):

Using KafkaCat offset param `-o` can be specified with negative value:

`kcat -b localhost:9092 -t mytopic -o -1`

Use `-o -5` for last 5 messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

With KafkaCat (https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/app-development/kafkacat-usage.html) last N messages of an Apache Kafka Topic can be read.

Comment: What is the command to get latest messages? Kafkacat is only displaying messages randomly but not the latest ones.

Answer (score -4):

I got probably correct answer from some googling http://grokbase.com/t/kafka/users/145x930s27/how-to-get-last-message

There someone suggest to find last offset with getOffsetBefore api and then
using that offset - 1 to fetch.

Comment: Link is not valid